# Program Debug Database files in a Release output folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, release

I've switched over my solution's **Build** configuration to *Release* mode and now have an output in the "Release" folder instead of in the "Debug" one.
But still the Release output contains **Program Debug Database** files. Why is that? When should I keep them, when and how should I get rid of them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The debug database files (.pdb or "symbol files") contain debug information, such as line numbers, to enable easier debugging.

When present, exception stack traces will contain the actual source file *full path* and *line number*.

It is up to you whether to distribute these along with your application.

In order to not create pdb files in Release configuration:

1. Go to your project's Properties.
2. Under "Build" tab, select "Advanced" (on the buttom).
   [image]
3. For "Debug Info", select "None".

Note that this will not affect any references assemblies (their .pdb files will be copied to your project's output folder.

Read more about Symbols here: [Program Database Files (C#, F#, and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241903(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be no difference if you deploy your application without these program debug databases as these files could be of great size.